# Nested for loops seem to execute separately for some reason

Tags: c, for-loop, nested

I am attempting to process a two-dimensional array in C. I tried two nested for loops, but it seems that the two loops execute separately. I expect that the inside loop loops eight times for each loop of the outside loop, resulting in eight times the number of outside loops being the total number of loops.

As a simplified test, I tried this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for (; x < 7; x++, printf("(%d,%d)", x, y)) {
        for (; y < 8; y++, printf("(%d,%d)", x, y)) { }
    }
}
```

This resulted in these results:

(0,1)(0,2)(0,3)(0,4)(0,5)(0,6)(0,7)(0,8)(1,8)(2,8)(3,8)(4,8)(5,8)(6,8)

Could somebody please explain to me why this might be happening? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is simple: you do not reinitialize the y variable in inner loop: when it reaches 8, it stays this way and the inner loop does not execute any more. Change your code to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    for (x=0; x < 7; x++, printf("(%d,%d)", x, y)) {
        for (y = 0; y < 8; y++, printf("(%d,%d)", x, y)) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh. Thanks so much! That was just the type of obvious mistake I knew I must have made. Thanks again!